# Excel Goal Seek Function

Tags: excel, vba

Any help on why the following code is throwing an Error 1004: "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

```
Sub Macro4()
    Dim j As Integer
    For j = 0 To 13  
      Cells(17, j).GoalSeek Goal:=101, ChangingCell:=Cells(16, j)
    Next j
End Sub
```

[image: image of data in worksheet]

Comment: There is no cell at column `0`

Comment: I changed it to 5 and still throwing an error

Comment: What is the error? what formula do you have in Row 17?  We need more info.

Comment: Row 17 has a sum of 10 rows which are divided by the row 16 value. Changing thew row 16 value will change the sum in row 17 to make it close to 101. I am receiving an error "Runtime error 1004"

Comment: What is actual formula? I get no errors after changing the 0 to a 1.  Show picture of how your page is set up.  And exactly what formula you have and where.

Comment: Scott I attached the picture.

Comment: Do you get an error if you do the goal seek manually? When stepping through the code, what is the value of j when you get the error?

Comment: You've changed `j` to start at 5 as per your comment, but the first column of interest is F, i.e. column 6, and the last column of interest is O, i.e. column 15.

Comment: Thank you all. I changed the column values and the issue got resolved.